# Is there a recommended / secure way to unlock an account through Web3 interface / HTML page securely?

Tags: web3js, security, accounts, json-rpc

This question was asked on Reddit:

> Is there a secure/recommended solution to unlock an account and send a tx through the Web3 interface (from a Html page)?
>
> One of the alternatives that I have in mind is just to disable the Rpc and create a layer, and expose custom methods through it.
>
> <sub>— [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/51t3zf/unlock_account_through_web3_securely)</sub>

Comment: It's perfectly fine to post good quality Q&A (not discussions) from other sites to here: http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6/should-we-get-questions-from-reddit-and-the-forums

Answer (score 6):

The safest way to do this is to not rely on unlocking the account at all; instead, use ethereumjs and web3 to build your app to hold keys itself, and generate transactions which you submit with `eth.sendRawTransaction`. That way, you can do key management yourself, your user only has to trust you with funds they send to their account in your app, and you don't need the user to be running a node with unlocked accounts (or a node at all, if you use something like Infura).

Comment: Is there a good tutorial or example for this?

Comment: Here's a tutorial that shows how to do it in a Truffle context -- i.e., create a custom web3 provider that you then use within a Truffle configuration. You should be able to extract the relevant bits out: http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider