# MetaMask: how can I access the web3 object locally and use my own node?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, security, dapp-development, metamask

I am new to Ethereum and was looking for a way to run my dApp in Chrome instead of Mist.

I encountered Metamask, which would in theory fit my needs perfectly. However, from a basic web point of view, it looks like Metamask is a proxy to an Ethereum node and web3 APIs, meaning all my blockchain dApp data would go through them.

Is Metamask working this way ? 
If yes, how could I use Chrome to develop my dApp, or rather how can I access the web3 object locally ? (I'm already running a json-rpc node)

My concern here is security and not relying on third parties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MetaMask does host a pre-synced blockchain cluster by default, and does its best to keep it online at all times, but it can easily be changed via the provider menu in the top left of the metamask popup.

If you'd rather use your local json-rpc node, just point MetaMask at its address.

From a security perspective, this allows you to run MetaMask as decentralized as Mist, by pointing it at your local RPC. This will allow you to develop a Dapp that is both Mist and Metamask compatible, and your users will be able to define their own blockchain connections according to their needs.

Comment: Thanks, good to know that you can point MetaMask to your local json-rpc node.

Answer (score 1):

you are right metmask is a 'proxy' or a bridge between you normal browser and Ethereum network. so in order to run your Dapp you need to use if you prefer to go through chrome.

Why we need it ? because chrome don't know how to run your Dapps specially to execute the web3js to send transaction or to communicate with the Ethereum node, it will allow you only to run the frontend (HTML/Css/javascript).

you could use [Mist](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases) which is a dedicated browser for Dapps. 
or you could send you command directly through [RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) to your node without using a browser.

concerning security :  [Geth RPC connections securely](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8837/geth-rpc-connections-securely)

[Is there a recommended / secure way to unlock an account through Web3 interface / HTML page securely?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8595/is-there-a-recommended-secure-way-to-unlock-an-account-through-web3-interface)

Comment: If I understood you weIl,  it's not possible to use Web3 in chrome without using Metamask ?  Because it is a full fledged API exposing all web3 methods ?

Comment: Exactly. Chrome is not designed to communicate with ethereum clients